# Spring @DynamicPropertySource does not work if an empty constructor is present in an @Configuration class

Tags: spring, testcontainers

I am using `TestContainers` for integration testing and i am using `@DynamicPropertySource` to set-up the `KafkaContainer` bootstrap servers like so:

```
@DynamicPropertySource
static void kafkaProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", () -> { 
        return kafkaContainer1.getHost() + ":" + kafkaContainer1.getFirstMappedPort();
    });
}
```

And this works like a charm, i.e as intended in my `KafkaTopicConfiguration` class:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaTopicConfiguration {

    private String bootstrapServers;

    public KafkaTopicConfiguration(@Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}") String bootstrapServers) {
        this.bootstrapServers = bootstrapServers;
    }
```

where `bootstrapServers` will get the address of the KafkaContainer exposed by Docker on the host.
Now, i added an empty constructor, because i wanted to troubleshoot something, like so:

```
public KafkaTopicConfiguration() {
    System.out.println("In KafkaTopicConfiguration constructor");
}
```

and suddenly the `boostrapServers` value become `null`. When i remove the empty constructor, it's back to normal. Does anyone know why? Thanks.

Comment: So you remove the assigning of a value to the field and find it strange it is `null`?

Comment: What do you mean @M.Deinum? Please explain, thanks!

Comment: Exactly as I'm saying. In the constructor, you pass in an argument and assign that to a field. You remove that and still expect the assignment to take place, that is not how things work.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, you misunderstood. The constructor that i added for troubleshooting is this: `public KafkaTopicConfiguration()`.

Comment: I didn’t misunderstand anything. It is you who isn’t understanding things. You add a constructor which assigns nothing and wonder why a field is null. The no-args constructor is used not the other one thus nothing will be assigned to the field.

Comment: Ohhhh, you are right!! Didn't think about that at all!!Thanks buddy!! You might want to write it as an answer, and i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @M.Deinum for pointing out my mistake. For posterity, i should have added the `@Autowired` annotation on my existing constructor, to tell Spring which constructor to use:

```
@Autowired
public KafkaTopicConfiguration(@Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}") String bootstrapServers) {
    this.bootstrapServers = bootstrapServers;
}
    
public KafkaTopicConfiguration() {
    System.out.println("In KafkaTopicConfiguration constructor");
}
```

My other constructor would have been useless though, and i should just have added the SysOut on the existing 1-arg constructor ;-)